# How can I generate a new string using the same function? (tkinter, python)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am creating a simple password generator, it should make a new one every time I press the button. How would I do that? Every time I do it, it prints/shows the same password. I think I understand why it's not working the way I want it to but I don't know how to fix it. Thank you.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
    
def password_generator():
    numbers = "1234567890"
    upper_case_letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    lower_case_letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    special_chars = "!@#$%^&*()[];:"
    
    password_length = random.randint(9, 15)
    
    combo = numbers + upper_case_letters + lower_case_letters + special_chars
    
    password = "".join(random.sample(combo, password_length))
    
    return password
    
    
def printSomething():
    label = Label(window, text = password)
    label.pack() 

password = password_generator()
window = Tk()
    
window.geometry("400x250")
window.title("Password Generator")
window.config(background = "black")

button = Button(window, text = "Generate")
button.pack()
button.config(command = printSomething) 
button.config(font = ("", 50, "bold")) 
    
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `password = password_generator()`, **when** do you expect that code to run? **How many times** should it run? Why? Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and carefully trace through the logic of the code before asking. Hint: you want the Label text to change when the button is clicked. When the button is clicked, `printSomething` runs. So - when should the password be randomized - inside that function, or outside? Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is running the function and returning a single generated password:

```py
password = password_generator()
```

So the password is already generated before you run the user interface.

Instead, remove this line, and generate a new password each time you call the function `printSomething()`, i.e. the function should be

```py
def printSomething():
    label = Label(window, text = password_generator())
    label.pack()
```

Notice that I replaced `password`, which already called the function and generated a single password, with `password_generator()`, which calls the function each time `printSomething()` is called. This way, a new password is generated every time the user clicks the button.